# strptime as unresolved reference

Tags: c++

I have an annoying issue with my C++ programs.  I have two programs (a main program and a small helper program that feeds it for testing) which I recenty moved from one system to another.  On the new system I started getting an unresolved reference error for the strptime method in the main program.  The annoying thing is that the helper program also has the same strptime method and is able to call it without any difficulty.  Strptime worked on the old system, both systems are running the same version of centos.

I've tried the obvious things to determine why my reference is unresolved.  I tried copying every header my helper program had to my main program and it's still unresolved.  I checked eclipse compiler/linker settings and while the main program does a few more things (adds some symbols, includes a few extra folders, and links to the libld) none of the changes seem to explain why one program could recognize strptime.  I tried to create a demo program that only used strptime and it was recognized.  I'm at a lost now for why I'm getting the error.  Can anyone suggest something else I could check for the potential caue of the unresolved reference?

I have verifid that time.h, which I'm linking, contains the strptime method, but it's defined externally.  Is there another .h that the time.h file should include which gives an inline definition of the method?

Comment: Please post the exact linker command and the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't seen this before, but this might help:

From the linux man pages...

http://linux.die.net/man/3/strptime

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE /* See feature_test_macros(7) */
#include <time.h>
```

---

_XOPEN_SOURCE - Feature Test Macro

Defining this macro causes header files to expose definitions as follows:
• Defining with any value exposes definitions conforming to POSIX.1, POSIX.2, and XPG4.
• The value 500 or greater additionally exposes definitions for SUSv2 (UNIX 98).

• (Since glibc 2.2) The value 600 or greater additionally exposes definitions for SUSv3 (UNIX 03; i.e., the POSIX.1-2001 base specification plus the XSI extension) and C99 definitions.

• (Since glibc 2.10) The value 700 or greater additionally exposes definitions for SUSv4 (i.e., the POSIX.1-2008 base specification plus the XSI extension).

Comment: I had thought I did this correctly, but if I go to the time.h file eclipse still says it's undefined.  Can you better tel me how to ensure this is #define correctly?  should I be sending some variable to the compiler using -D to ensure it's defined before any .H in a large project?  also; any clue why this wouldn't be nessesary for my other two projects?

Comment: okay I have _GNU_SOURCE passed to the compile and #defined in my cpp file.  I get a waring saying I'm redefiing _GNU_SOURCE in my file, but yet I still can't use strptime and if I go to the time.h file eclipse tells me __XOPEN_SOURCE is still undefined.  I thought if _GNU_SOURCE is defined I'm set?  I've also tried setting XOPEN_SOURCE directly and it idn't work either.  AM I missing something?

Comment: @dsollen Sorry, just read all that.  Did you get it to compile & link now?

Comment: nope, still acting odd.  was considering re-asking the question now that I better understand the problem though lol

Comment: Probably for the best, haha.  Just delete this one, it's not helpful to anyone.